# angularjs - ng repeat with json

Tags: javascript, angularjs

how can i use `ng-repeat` for below `json`

```js
$scope.prlists = {
  "1": [{
    "id": "1",
    "name": "One",
    "qty": 2,
    "amount": "1.00",
    "cat": "1.00"
  }],
  "3": [{
    "id": "3",
    "name": "backit",
    "qty": 3,
    "amount": "2.00",
    "cat": "2.00"
  }]
}
```

```html
<div ng-repeat="pro in prlists">
  name : pro.name
</div>
```

can not able to get the name due to inner array. How to solve

Comment: try `name : pro[0].name`

Comment: The data-object can be make better to make it easy for iterate over it. Use array of objects. `var data = [{ athing: 'something', ...}, {}, ..];`

Comment: Your data structure is very odd, for the data you are showing;  You have an Object which has multiple properties you are trying to iterate over, and each property has an Array that only contains one element... Normalizing your data to use an Array where there are multiple elements and an Object in each Array node would make much more sense.

Comment: Refer angular doc : https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I have already commented:

> try pro[0].name

#### Reason:

In you code, for every iteration, $data(`pro`) will have

```
[{
  "id": "1",
  "name": "One",
  "qty": 2,
  "amount": "1.00",
  "cat": "1.00"
}]
```

Now as you see, this is not an object, so you have to go to its first and only child. Also you are missing `{{}}`. `name : pro.name` this will print `pro.name` as text and not parse it.

**[Working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/RajeshDixit/HB7LU/23047/).**

Comment: Perfectly working fine from the demo . Could you please tell me  i can display the Name, Qty, Amount, Total(qty x amount)  in loop. I want to provide + and - icon to increase /decrease  the qty same time the total amount need to change based on changed qty..... Need to update the JSON array..... same like get final total for complete list .. Please help me find the proper solution From your demo

Comment: Thank you perfectly working .. try to get the net total..  check this Total: {{getTotal}}                                                                                $scope.getTotal = function(){
        var total = 0;
       
        return total;
    }

Comment: {{nettotal}}$scope.nettotal = function(){
  var total = 0;
        for(var i = 0; i < $scope.prlists.length; i++){
            var pr = $scope.prlists[i];
            
            total += (pr.amount * pr.qty);
        }
        return total;
}

Answer (score 2):

`ngRepeat` can iterate over object properties. So, you can do something like

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, pro) in prlists">
    name: {{pro[0].name}}
</div>
```

See the documentation at: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngRepeat

Note that this will not guarantee the order in Angular version >= 1.4, since it will depend on the browser's ordering. You might be able to sort it using the `orderBy` filter

```
<div ng-repeat="(key, pro) in prlists | orderBy:key">
    name: {{pro[0].name}}
</div>
```

See: https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/filter/orderBy

If the inner arrays are not just a single element, you may have to nest a second `ngRepeat` inside the first div.

Comment: In HTML, filter arguments are separated by colons `<div ng-repeat="(key, pro) in prlists | orderBy : key">`

Comment: @georgeawg Thanks, fixed.